# PHP connect to MS SQL

Tags: php, sql-server, sql

Здравствуйте.

Решил попробовать связать БД от Microsoft и PHP.

Добавил в ext необходимые dll

Код PHP

```
    <?php
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect("localhost\sqlexpress");
    $sql = "SELECT Abonents.id FROM Abonents";
    if ($conn) {
        echo "Connection established.\n";
        $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
        if( $result === false) {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
        }           
        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
            echo $row['id']."<br />";
        }
    } 
    else {
        echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
    sqlsrv_close($conn);
    ?>
```

Вот что имею в браузере

Connection established. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42S02 [SQLSTATE] => 42S02 [1] => 208 [code] => 208 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]������������ ��� ������� "Abonents". [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]������������ ��� ������� "Abonents". ) )

Что делать с кодировкой?(в PHP.ini что-то менять или в коде страницы)
Что значит эта ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, база не выбрана.

Сообщение об ошибке, вероятно, сообщает, что таблица Abonents не обнаружена в текущей базе данных (master, скорее всего).